# How to create an array from a collection

Tags: c#, collections

A collection is passed to the function parameters. I need to take an element in the middle from it. How can i do this?

```
private PaperProduct midEl(ICollection<Type> Coll)
        {
            int index = (Coll.Count() / 2)+1;
            Type T = Coll.GetType();
            Coll.CopyTo(T[], 10);
        }
```

Comment: Unclear whar you are asking. To create an array from a collection, you can use Linq: `coll.ToArray()`. To access an element in an `ICollection<T>` , you can use `ElementAt(index)`.

Comment: `var result = Coll.ElementAt(Coll.Count / 2 + 1);`

Comment: Why do you want to create an array? And what if the collection is null or empty? Why the + 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just convert the collection to an array and take the index.

```
var middle = Coll.ToArray()[index];
```

Or more simple and without conversion:

```
var middle = Coll.ElementAt(index);
```